# trying to run outside exe file from python freezes

Tags: python, windows, os.system

I'm trying to run an executable file called `CDQ.exe` (which is supposed to create a text file) from within a python script. I'm using `os.system(CDQ.exe)`  to run it. When I start the python script, the program freezes upon the  `os.system()` call. I also don't get the text file. When I opened the task manager, I found `CDQ` was still running, and it kept running until I ended it.

When I try to run the `CDQ.exe` from the windows file browser by clicking it twice, the program appears for a couple of seconds in the task manager, then it closes, and my text file appears.

The executable file was created from c++ qt, and I'm using windows.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: my fist action would be to try running the `CDQ.exe` using the cmd, it may be waiting on user input or something when running from a terminal, which is the same case as running inside `os.system()`, which might be solvable by communicating the input using the subprocess module, another thing that could happen is that the program may be running into internal problems when running under python due to a dependency conflict, so you might want to check if you are setting any extra environment variables under python that may be conflicting with the program like modifying the `PATH` variable.

Comment: I have tried running it from cmd and it gave some insights. It seems that I had to change directory to executable file location using `os.chdir(D\LD\executable)` then I had to use `os.system(CDQ.exe)` and it worked. What I was doing earlier is `os.system(D\LD\executable\CDQ.exe)` which made the executable go into a loop, but I'm not sure why. 
All good, thanks a lot.